# Transpile npm module in Next.js

Tags: webpack, node-modules, next.js

I am trying to transpile a module "react-device-detect" from node_modules but unable to achieve yet. Following is what I have tried:

```js
module.exports = withLess({
  webpack: (config, { isServer, defaultLoaders }) => {
    // other configs
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\\.+(ts|tsx)$/,
      include: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-device-detect')],
      // exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader' }],
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\\.+(js|jsx)$/,
      include: [path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-device-detect')],
      // exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
    });
    return config;
  },
});
```

I have tried the rules individually as well but didn't work.

**UPDATE 1:**
Complete next.config.js configurations @felixmosh

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const { parsed: localEnv } = require("dotenv").config();
require("dotenv").config({
  path: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? ".env.production" : ".env"
});
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");

module.exports = withLess({
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
    config.node = {
      fs: "empty"
    };
    // add env variables on client end
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(localEnv));
    config.plugins.push(new Dotenv());

    if (!isServer) {
      config.resolve.alias["@sentry/node"] = "@sentry/browser";
    }
    return config;
  }
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

It seems that `next-transpile-modules` does not work comfortably with `next-i18next`. I got in IE browser's console:

```
'exports' is undefined
```

I got errors like following when I run `npm run build`:

```js
./utils.js
Attempted import error: 'isMobileSafari' is not exported from 'react-device-detect'.

./utils.js
Attempted import error: 'isMobileSafari' is not exported from 'react-device-detect'.

./utils.js
Attempted import error: 'osName' is not exported from 'react-device-detect'.
```

I got following when I run `npm start`:

`react-i18next:: i18n.languages were undefined or empty undefined`

Comment: why does your original config not work even though you are explicitly adding the module to be transpiled using webpack ?

Comment: Check this answer here if you are using Next.js 13
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74255025/1901574

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an NPM module for this [`next-transpile-modules`](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules#readme) that allows you to specify which modules to transpile.

```js
// next.config.js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['somemodule', 'and-another']); // pass the modules you would like to see transpiled

module.exports = withTM(withLess({
  ... // your custom next config

}));
```

#### Edit:

As of [Next 13.1](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-1#built-in-module-transpilation-stable), there is a built in support for transpiling given packages.

```js
// next.config.js

const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['@acme/ui', 'lodash-es'],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: So how would I combine both configs in the export because I have other configs as well that I didn't include here because they were irrelevant to the question?

Comment: I have added the errors I got in **UPDATE 2** in my question.

Comment: Is next-i18next is that package that u wanna to transpile? Why? It provides cjs version out of the box

Comment: No, I want to transpile react-device-detect only. But it gives errors as I have described in the **UPDATE 2** if I include only `react-device-detect` or even if I include `next-i18next`.

Comment: I do see that react-detect-device has a build step to convert it to cjs, what is the problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: Could you please help me with this cjs thing, I get Object.includes is not a function on IE and the stack trace points to this `react-device-detect`. So that's why I wanted to include it in transpile process to get it converted into compatible es5 version.

Comment: Sorry it was Array.includes is not a function.

Comment: Transpiling it won't solve the issue, you need to provide a pollyfill. the simplest way is to use https://polyfill.io/

Comment: Just add https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js to your page, it should provide a browser specific polyfill (in this way modern browsers won't download redundant code)

Comment: Thank the gods for you, fam.

Answer (score 4):

From **Next.JS** `13.1+` you can use property `transpilePackages` in `next.config.js`

```js
const nextConfig = {
  transpilePackages: ['the-npm-package'],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```