# Implement pusher for real-time web notifications in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, real-time, pusher, web-notifications

I am getting the below error after initializing pusher on nextjs application:

```
export { Client, RegistrationState, TokenProvider };
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I have also tried modifying the next.config.js file to the following:

```
const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")(["@pusher/push-notifications-web"])
module.exports = withTM({
  env: {
    apiBaseUrl: "",
    apiBaseUrlChat: ""
  },
});
```

When I am trying to execute `npm run dev`, it is giving me the following error:

```
TypeError: modules.map is not a function
```

Comment: This looks to have been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936222/next-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export. In short, you may need to: 

Try to modify the webpack config in next.config.js file to let the babel loader transpile the es6 dependency. You may want to use this package next-transpile-modules

Comment: Thanks for your response @doydoy, can you share code sample for that?

Comment: The problem for me was that the lib I used was missing an entry file. What fixed it for me was to add an empty `index.js` to the package, doing so `next-transpile-modules` worked and I was able to use the lib. Sounds stupid, but that did the job in my case.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. But I don't push node_modules file to the server. I can't do that.

Comment: @hs27 But you could try to manually add an index.js to your client's `node_modules` to check whether or not this is the issue.

Comment: @Tim I tried that, but I get the following error:

`ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: custom webpack configuration in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
info  - automatically enabled Fast Refresh for 1 custom loader
(node:18500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined `