# NextJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a library that works flawless on a app using react-create-app. Now, I want to use this library with NextJS (using `npx create-next-app --ts`) but I got this error:

````
error - /home/ubuntu/workspace/uikit-showcase-next/node_modules/@orgname/uikit/index.js:1
export * from './components/atom';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1036:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.@orgname/uikit (/home/ubuntu/workspace/uikit-showcase-next/.next/server/pages/index.js:87:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/ubuntu/workspace/uikit-showcase-next/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object../pages/index.tsx (/home/ubuntu/workspace/uikit-showcase-next/.next/server/pages/index.js:20:75) {
  page: '/'
}```
````

Comment: Please Make sure You have the latest version of node and than run npx create-next-app --ts, good luck and best regards ! ;-)

Comment: I am using node 14

Comment: node --version: v14.17.6 and npm --version: 6.14.15

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js SyntaxError "Unexpected token 'export'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936222/next-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)? Use [`next-transpile-modules`](https://github.com/martpie/next-transpile-modules) to transpile your library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed on the library from `"target": "es6",` to `"target": "es5",` solved the issue