# Server Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to integrate [an animation plugin](https://luge.cool/) into a NextJS application. Running locally and on a sandbox, I'm receiving a

*'Server Error SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'*

error right after installing and importing the plugin.

This happens even in a completely blank setup, where only the plugin in question is imported:

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-moon-5vxeh?file=/pages/index.js

Having looked through countless entries on SO that referred to this issue, the root cause was related to either Node, Babel or ES6, but have left me with no possible hint on where to starting fixing this issue inside a NextJS application.

Where within the application could this issue be solved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js SyntaxError "Unexpected token 'export'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936222/next-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for this specific plugin, a straightforward import does not work.

The plugin needs to be wrapped into a separate component with useEffect:

```
    import { useEffect } from "react"

const LugeReact = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    import("@waaark/luge/dist/js/luge")
      .then((luge) => {
        luge.lifecycle.refresh()
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  })

  return (null);
}

export default LugeReact
```

And then imported to be used.