# How do I resolve SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' in react nextjs project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am working on a react nextjs project, and I suddenly ran into a SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' error.

I have read the solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936222/next-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export) but I don't seem to understand it to correctly apply the suggested answers.

Is it something that has to do with nextjs compiling error?
How do I best resolve it?
[image: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export]

Here's a screenshot of my package.json [image: package.json content]

Comment: use ```import { BsInstagram } from "react-icons/bs";``` instead of ```import { BsInstagram } from "react-icons/all";```

Answer (score 5):

I later found a solution on Github - [Syntax Error: Unexpected token export](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-tailwind/issues/84)
The issue has something to do with ES modules in next.js and the solution was to install `next-transpile-modules` using:

`npm i next-transpile-modules`.

Thereafter, I added the following to my next.config.js file:

`const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(["react-icons"]);`

`module.exports = withTM({})`

This solves the error (for me).

You will need to put the name of the affected node module in place of `react-icons` for it to work in your case.

Comment: I already have content in the module.exports object.  How do I combine with existing object?  My code: https://pastebin.com/TtAxKqfC

Comment: Thank you good people, another note: if you have your own nextConfig, just input it inside withTM()

Answer (score 0):

I too did face such a error in nextjs. 
What I did was seperating the declaration and exporting statment of the function/constant into seperate lines.

Yet I'm not sure if it's the same issue you are going through, Could you please send the code of the `next.config.js` and whatever the scripts that are creating this error.

Comment: Thanks.

Please find my next.config.js content below...

```/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig```