# How do I package a local TypeScript package with dependencies for use in other local Next.js projects?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am working on a project where I have the following structure:

```
/         # repository root
/core     # A local, unpublished npm package used by both projectA and projectB
/projectA # A Next.js app
/projectB # Another Next.js app
```

I have a `/core/package.json` and `/core/tsconfig.json` that get `tsc && npm pack`'d into a single `core-1.0.0.tgz` file. This *appears* to be all working; the `tsc` and `npm pack` commands complete without error, and the `.tgz` file seems to have all of the transpiled `.js` code that I am expecting.

`/core/tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2022", "DOM"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2022",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": ".compiled",
    "declaration": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["./index.ts"]
}
```

`/core/package.json`

```
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.15.0"
  },
  "main": "./.compiled/index.js",
  "types": "./.compiled/index.d.ts",
  "files":[
    "./.compiled/**"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "ts-node ./tests.ts",
    "build": "npm install && npm run test && tsc && npm pack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@uppy/aws-s3": "3.3.1",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I then add my `core` package to `projectA` by adding the following to `/projectA/package.json`:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "core": "../core/core-1.0.0.tgz",
  ...
},
...
```

I run `npm install` in `/projectA`, and things also appear to be working. I look in `projectA/node_modules` and I not only see my `core` folder with the transpiled JS, but I also see the `dependencies` from `core` have been lifted out and installed into `projectA/node_modules`.

When I *run* `projectA`, however, I am immediately greeted by an error from a `core` import that says:

```
Error: require() of ES Module C:\dev\repo\projectA\node_modules\@uppy\aws-s3\lib\index.js from C:\dev\repo\projectA\node_modules\core\.compiled\library\components\file-uploader\FileUploader.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\dev\repo\projectA\node_modules\core\.compiled\library\components\file-uploader\FileUploader.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

`@uppy/aws-s3` is one of the sub-dependencies of `core`. `FileUploader.js` is a transpiled version of a `FileUploader.ts` React component I've created that provides a little UI wrapper around `@uppy`. I see the words from the error message, but I am a tad lost between the layers. I suspect I need to change something in my `/core/tsconfig.json`, but I haven't been able to find a lead on *what* exactly might need to change.

`/core/.../FileUploader.ts`

```
import UppyAwsS3 from '@uppy/aws-s3'
import Uppy, { SuccessResponse, UppyFile } from '@uppy/core'
import UppyDashboard from '@uppy/dashboard'
import cx from 'classnames'
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  className?: string
  fullWidth: boolean
  ...
}

interface State {}

class FileUploader extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  ...
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div className={cx('FileUploader', this.props.className, this.props.fullWidth && 'FileUploader--fullWidth')}>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default FileUploader
```

`/projectA/tsconfig.json`, for reference

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["ES2022", "dom"],
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Does anyone have any insight into how I can get this shared TypeScript package set up? Does anything look off in what I have?

**Edit** It has been suggested to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396400/how-to-use-es6-modules-in-commonjs). This is unfortunately not the same. I am writing TypeScript, not raw vanilla JS. I am asking how to get `tsc` to compile the correct import syntax so that Next.js can utilize my shared FileUploader component from my `core` CommonJS package that has a dependency on the ESM package `@uppy/aws-s3`.

**Update:** I have created a minimal sample project that shows the error. It is [available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vXAVAAIW_8wfh9CicziryQgI4vUNR-uI/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use ES6 modules in CommonJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396400/how-to-use-es6-modules-in-commonjs)

Comment: I have been looking at similar answers as well, the problem I am running into is that all of these reference straight vanilla `Node.js` projects. I can't just change my imports because I am not writing the imports; the TypeScript compiler is. So I need to find some way to get the TypeScript compiler to create the correct imports, right?

Comment: That's a valid issue, which I also haven't found a good solution to yet. Try using dynamic import syntax instead: `await import("@uppy/aws-s3")`

Comment: Thanks @ParzhfromUkraine! I was not able to get that to work yesterday either. TypeScript kept transpiling the `import()` call to a CommonJS `require`. Sounds like this [has been a problem in Typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43329). The couple of ideas from that thread were to wrap the import in an `eval`  (tried this, but the module could still not be resolved at runtime), or to change the `"moduleResolution": "Node16"`. `Node16` is not compatible with `"module": "CommonJS"` though -- `tsc` says it's only valid with `ES/Node` module settings.

Comment: Could be worth breaking that off into a separate question of `Why can't Next.js find my dynamic import`. It doesn't feel like a dead end; I just haven't able to make it work yet.

Comment: No matter whatever setup you use, the only thing works well is to publish npm package on some npm repository and accessing it easily. If you do not want to publish to global/public npm repository, you can use private repositories such as gitlab's self hosted instance or any other repository and import packages from there. The best part is you will be able to version your setup clearly.

Comment: Thanks, Akash! Yeah, I struggled a little bit even getting the point that I am at. I originally had my `core` imported in package.json using `"core": "../core/.compiled"` and that was *definitely* not working the way it should. Tarball'ing, however, is exactly what happens when `npm publish`ing to the NPM repository, and linking to that tarball does what you think it should. I do not believe this is a problem with the package linking itself in Node.js; I suspect there is something off in my Typescript configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get my example to compile & link successfully! After a lot of dead ends & tool research, I was able to get things running *without* installing any additional packages, dependencies, or tools.

Here's what changed:

- `core/tsconfig.json`

  - per [Icekid's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77441989/6100384), changed `compilerOptions.module` and `compilerOptions.target` to `ES6`.
  - Add `compilerOptions.moduleResolution: "Node"`; without this TypeScript didn't seem to like my `import` statements when running `tsc`.
- `projectA/next.config.js`

  - Add `transpilePackages: ['core']`. [This is a quirk of Next.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936222/next-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export); it's compiler does *not* auto-transpile locally imported ES6 modules down per the `tsconfig.json`. Quite frustrating, since importing `uppy/aws-s3` (which is an ES6 module) manually in `projectA` *does* seem to transpile correctly with no complaint from Next.js. I have no idea why some packages are able to be auto-transpiled, but my custom local `core` package needs to be manually told to get transpiled.

That was it. All other settings were able to remain.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/)

> Lerna is a fast, modern build system for managing and publishing
> multiple JavaScript/TypeScript packages from the same repository.

Basically, Lerna is for managing multi project packages.

```
lerna init
```

will create packages directory and you place packages here. you can link those packages with

```
 lerna add shared --scope=packageA
```

you can add the `shared` module into `packageA` node modules. When you add this dependency, you use the `name` in the `package.json` of shared module

```
 // in packge,json of packageA
  "dependencies": {
    "nameOfPackageJsonOfSharedModule": "^1.0.0",
  }
```

at this point, you should be able to use `shared` module inside `packageA`

```
//  "nameOfPackageJsonOfSharedModule" this is the name of dependency above
const share=require("nameOfPackageJsonOfSharedModule")
```

if this does not work, you could build each package and use the build directory when importing modules. let's say you built `shared` module, in `package.json` of `shared` module, add this

```
 // when you import name this package, build/index.js will be executed
 "bin":"build/index.js""
```

Comment: Thanks Yilmaz! Pointing the `package.json` straight to `"core": "../core/.compiled"` is oddly enough not the same as running a regular `npm install`. I ran into this issue early on with this setup. If you just link to the `core/.compiled` build, none of the `core/dependencies` get lifted into `projectA`. The `uppy` dependencies do not get lifted into the `projectA`. Tarball'ing through `npm pack` solves this issue, and is exactly what happens when the project gets `published` to `npm`.

Comment: Similar to the Mayank's answer -- I'm not opposed to using different/additional tools like `Lerna` to get this working, but it *feels* like what I am trying to accomplish here should be possible with just straight Typescript.

Comment: I did add a demo codebase that has a minimal setup of what I am running into, if that helps diagnose anything!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `"module": "commonjs"` in the `compilerOptions`. You may need to modify other things a little depending on your exact configuration.

However, I would like to encourage you to use TurboRepo setup, which is officially supported by Next.js. You can check out [this template repo](https://github.com/mayank1513/turborepo-template/) if it helps.

Some of the packages I have published using this setup

- https://github.com/mayank1513/turborepo-template/ (The main template)
- https://github.com/mayank1513/react18-themes/
- https://github.com/mayank1513/esbuild-plugin-react18

Feel free to explore more.

Comment: Hey Mayank! Setting the `module` to `CommonJS` in the `projectA/tsconfig.json` has no effect; the error message is exactly the same. I am not opposed to using `TurboRepo`, but this feels like something that *should* be possible without completely gutting the build system of Next.js.

Comment: I did add a demo codebase that has a minimal setup of what I am running into, if that helps diagnose anything!

Answer (score 0):

instead of npm, use pnpm. It packages your dependencies to use directly in other projects

https://pnpm.io/.

Comment: how so? what does it do differently that makes it do what you claim npm can't do here? I've used pnpm and have an idea of how it works and I don't see what difference is of significance as it relates to this question.

Comment: npm does this for every project. For example if you have 5 projects having same packages, every project takes 3gb, but using pnmp, all projects will be take 3gb

Comment: I know. so what? how does that help with solving the problem in the question post?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35240708)