# NextJS SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' on node_modules

Tags: reactjs, next.js, import

I am trying to test/switch a Vite+React repo to NextJS+React.
After making the basic changes i got this error:

```
/.../repo-name/node_modules/react-router-typing/dist/index.js:1
export { generateUtils } from "./generate-utils";

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I tried changing `tsconfig` from `esnext` to `es5` but there were no changes in the error message.
The error is thrown in the `react-router-typing` and I can't make changes to the `node_module`.
The import location looks like so:

```js
import { defineRoutes, asBrowserRouter, AsRouteConfig, generateUtils } from 'react-router-typing'

...

export const { pagePath, pageMatch } = generateUtils<RouteConfig>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the library to the`transpilePackages` in `next.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    transpilePackages: [
        'react-router-typing',
    ],
}

export default nextConfig
```

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936222/next-js-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-export).